# Вызов функций класса в include

Tags: php, классы, include

Есть файлы
index.php

```
$c = new demo();
$c = $c->mysql();
include('demo.php');
```

demo.php

```
mysql_query(запрос);   
  $c->test();
```

запрос сработал, а вот функция нет.
ошибка

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object /demo.php
```

Если в файле демо снова объявить класс `(new demo())`, то работает, но разве класс не должен инициироваться?
Есть ли решения другие решения, нежели чем в каждом `include` файле объвлять его?

Answer (score 1):

> снова объявить класс(new demo())

Создать экземпляр класса. Класс объявляется только раз.

Теперь немного внимания:

```
$c = new demo();
$c = $c->mysql();
```

`$c` в этот момент становится тем, что возвращает `$c->mysql()`. Сомневаюсь, что это тот же самый экземпляр.

> и есть ли решения чем в каждом include файле объвлять его?

посмотрите паттерн Registry.